# SQLite db for native mobile app using angular

Tags: angular, sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have developed the angular app and converted it to mobile app using cordova. As angular app does not support SQLite so I am not using DB in that .. but in the mobile app I would like to DB to store some information offline .

Is there any way I can use SQlite in the mobile app which is using the same source code which get compiled to Android platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use cordova plugin for SQLite.. but you can only able to test your mobile app code in android emulator.

Comment: I have installed the Cordova plugin .. but where do I have put the code to open the connection to connect with SQlite . Because I am converting the angular code to mobile app .

Comment: in deviceReady event of cordova